# Render Salesforce Document Object Instance Body on Visualforce Page

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce, documents

I have a PDF file stored in Documents in Salesforce.  I need to get the Document from the Document object and render it as a PDF visualforce page.  When I get the body of the docuemnt it is the form of a BLOB.  However when I try to convert this to a string I get a "BLOB is not a valid UTF-8 string" error.
Can I access/render the returned BLOB on my visualforce page?  Currently it just renders as
"core.filemanager.FileBlobValue@4fle23d3"  when I use it within an apex:outputText.

Any suggestions on this would be welcomed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is on how to scrape text from a pdf in Salesforce?

If so, use [Apache Tika](https://tika.apache.org/) to convert your file to text and display this in your Visualforce page.

You will need to setup a server running Tika, and then make calls to it from your controller.